# How to redirect from last fragment to specific fragment on last fragment backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have a problem about removing a specific `Fragment` from `Backstack`.

Like, I have Five `Fragments A -> B -> C -> D -> E` and all `Fragments` call from same `Activity with add to Backstack` and add not use replace.

`Calling order; A -> B -> C -> D -> E`.

When `Fragment-E (last fragment)` is my current `Fragment` and pressed the `Back Button` then I want to go `Fragment-B`. That means I don’t require `Fragment-C, Fragment-D and Fragment-E`.

Also, When `Fragment B` is there and presses `back button` then `Fragment A` will be called. This will also happen with all the `fragment` simultaneously.

One more thing All `Fragment` call `API` to fetch data from the `server` and fill to list.

Help to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method called `instanceof` for `Fragments`. So when you are in `Fragment E` try to check like

while adding do `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentC");`

```
if(currentFragment instanceOf FragmentE) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack ("fragmentC", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

Comment: @Avinsh Ravilla, How to do pop, Because I have tried to remove but stuck on the same fragment E.

Comment: @Janak I edited my post with `popBackStack` code. you can do that for all the fragments you want to pop

Answer (score 0):

You need to `override onBackPressed()` in your `Activity`, From where your added `Fragment`.
You can create your own logic. like check if `current fragment` is `instanceof FragmentE` You need to call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` three time to remove  `Fragments C -> D -> E`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

        if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ad_container) instanceof FragmentE) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            // pop fragment D,C from backstack
            // navigate to fragment B
        }

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Hope this will help**

Comment: onBackPressed I Have done so many other operations using the instance of the fragment (for other fragments). so for this, I have to check a specific fragment is this correct??

Comment: Yes you to have to check specific fragment and manage it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In you activity Override onBackPressed() method and add below code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            if (fragment instanceof FragmentE) {
                     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack ("fragmentC", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            } 
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Remember don't forget to add `.addToBackStack("whichFragment")` before `transaction.commit();` while adding each fragments.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack ("fragmentC", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) //this essentially means also remove FragmentC
```